# Sonar Issue - Version update

Tags: sonarqube

Sonar is an open platform to manage code quality. I have the admin access to perform the updates. Recently I tried performing a version update from 3.7.3 to 4.1.1.Unfortunately 4.1.1 is only compatible with IE9 or above. Hence I back out the changes as in our organization IE8 is the internet browser. Now 3.7.3 is not working as it is showing as database is pointing to a latest version.MySQL is used to hold the sonar data. I am completely stuck with the issue. Sonar is a very important tool for us as this can only take a code coverage metrics for the source code.

May I request you to look in to this issue and provide some help. I cannot move forward without your help.

Anticipating your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get back to a normal state is to start over from a 3.7.3 database backup.

Comment: Hi David, Does that means to get back to a normal state only possible if I had a 3.7.3 database backup?

Comment: Hi David, I have created a new database for 3.7.3 but now wheh I am running sonar report I am getting the following error."class org.jacoco.core.internal.flow.ClassProbesVisitor has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class" Kindly help.

Comment: Please open a new thread and detail your issue because from the few information provided, I don't see any link to SonarQube.